# Testing three points for collinearity in a numerically robust way

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, numerical-methods

You can test that three 2D points, `a`, `b`, and `c`, fall on a line by noting the slope of line segment (`a`,`b`) will have to be the same as that of (`b`,`c`), or by noting that the area of the triangle they define will be zero if and only if the three points are collinear. I chose the former method because the math seemed more concise: [this answer contains the formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/405981/63016).

The trouble with the above is that although the mathematics is perfectly correct when we translate the test into code we find it behaves poorly given the fundamental imprecision of floating point types. Consider the following C++:

```cpp
using point = std::tuple<float, float>;

bool are_collinear(point a, point b, point c, float eps) {
    auto [a_x, a_y] = a;
    auto [b_x, b_y] = b;
    auto [c_x, c_y] = c;

    auto test = (b_x - a_x) * (c_y - a_y) - (c_x - a_x) * (b_y - a_y);
    return std::abs(test) < eps;
}

int main()
{
    point a = { 28.8171,77.9103 };
    point b = { 55.7515,75.5051 };
    point c = { 122.831,69.8003 };

    std::cout << "are_collinear(a, b, c, 0.01) => "
        << (are_collinear(a, b, c, 0.001) ? "yes\n" : "no\n"); // no

    std::cout << "are_collinear(a, b, c, 0.1) => "
        << (are_collinear(a, b, c, 0.1) ? "yes\n" : "no\n"); // no

    std::cout << "are_collinear(a, b, c, 10) => "
        << (are_collinear(a, b, c, 10) ? "yes\n" : "no\n"); // yes
}
```

The three points in that code look like this:

[image]

What is happening is that `test` in `are_collinear(...)` works out to approximately 7.685 which is way outside of a typical value we would think of as an acceptable error. The problem here is that the terms in the formula are products of relative lengths in absolute coordinates e.g. `(b_x - a_x) * (c_y - a_y)`. In order to make this function behave better we need to normalize the coordinates in some way.

Below I scale the coordinates such that the longest side of triangle (a,b,c) is 1 unit in length:

```cpp
using point = std::tuple<float, float>;

float distance(point a, point b) {
    auto [a_x, a_y] = a;
    auto [b_x, b_y] = b;
    auto x_diff = a_x - b_x;
    auto y_diff = a_y - b_y;
    return std::sqrt(x_diff * x_diff + y_diff * y_diff);
}

float max_distance(point a, point b, point c) {
    auto d1 = distance(a, b);
    auto d2 = distance(b, c);
    auto d3 = distance(a, c);
    return std::max(d1, std::max(d2, d3));
}

bool are_collinear(point a, point b, point c, float eps) {
    auto scale = max_distance(a, b, c);
    if (scale == 0)
        return true; // they are the same point.

    auto [a_x, a_y] = a;
    auto [b_x, b_y] = b;
    auto [c_x, c_y] = c;

    a_x /= scale;
    a_y /= scale;
    b_x /= scale;
    b_y /= scale;
    c_x /= scale;
    c_y /= scale;

    auto test = (b_x - a_x) * (c_y - a_y) - (c_x - a_x) * (b_y - a_y);
    return std::abs(test) < eps;
}

int main()
{
    point a = { 28.8171,77.9103 };
    point b = { 55.7515,75.5051 };
    point c = { 122.831,69.8003 };

    std::cout << "are_collinear(a, b, c, 0.01) => "
        << (are_collinear(a, b, c, 0.001) ? "yes\n" : "no\n"); // yes

    std::cout << "are_collinear(a, b, c, 0.1) => "
        << (are_collinear(a, b, c, 0.1) ? "yes\n" : "no\n"); // yes

    std::cout << "are_collinear(a, b, c, 10) => "
        << (are_collinear(a, b, c, 10) ? "yes\n" : "no\n"); // yes
}
```

The above fixes the problem but I have two problems with it (1) it is arbitrary in the sense that I made up the scaling factor by intuition and (2) I chose the slope method originally because the code was a one-liner; the new version is substantially longer so choosing this test for concision no longer makes sense.

Is there a better way to perform this test than my second version and are there any problems with that code that I am missing?

Comment: if you want precision don't use floating point numbers, changing to `double` at least might improve it

Comment: precision, per se, isnt actually the problem here. but yeah, this is just code for stackoverflow

Comment: You may try the area test. The area = abs| (b-a) x (c-a)|, and check if area < eps. The x is cross product. The code happens to be rather easy.

Comment: area test has the same problem though. the area you end up testing will have a size that is a function of absolute coordinates. So for fixed epsilon the same three points will fail your test if you scale them up by a factor of 100 or something. You'd need to normalize the points to get arond this. that is what this question is about.

Comment: The source code looks reasonable, but this is not the right site to ask people to look at it. You may want Stack Exchange - Code Review.

Comment: Slope is not a good item. It depends on the angle of slop. Horizontal has slop zero, and vertical has divergent slop. Either cases are troblesome.

Comment: The smoother method here is using calculation of angle between vectors. See [here](https://onlinemschool.com/math/library/vector/angl/) for example. Your method is pretty much comparing tangenses of angles between the vectors and 0X or 0Y axes which is not so rubust - it will depend on which direction you've chosen to work with.

Comment: https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00344310/ is a nice reference. How do you want to define collinear? Any notion of approximate collinearity will have strange properties, but deciding exact collinearity will require extra precision in some cases (the most common options are a bignum type or an expansion as a sum of floating point numbers). By the way, it is easier to multiply eps by scale instead of dividing every coordinate.

Comment: " By the way, it is easier to multiply eps by scale instead of dividing every coordinate" 
yes ... good suggestion. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a numerically meaningful test, consider the (double) area over the length of the longest side. This gives you the deviation of the middle point from the line by the two others. It is in units of length.

Answer (score 2):

If your coordinates are represented as floating point numbers with *limited* precision, then there is no way to correctly perform the collinearity test for *all* possible cases - it means that you'll inevitably meet some cases when this test will give you wrong results.

You could try the [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/) library, where this problem has been solved using more sophisticated coordinate representation. Actually, the collinearity test is used in the CGAL tutorial to explain differences between such representations - please read [this](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/tutorial_hello_world.html#intro_Three) page for more information.